# What is the difference between Light and Motion's Urban 800 Chainbreaker and Urban 800 Anchor Steam bike lights?

Tags: headlights

The only difference I can see is the color, but their website lists them as separate products. 
http://www.lightandmotion.com/choose-your-light/urban

Comment: Toggling between the two product pages they appear identical except name and colour, and the order of the recommended accessories. So I'm going to agree, it seems to be just colour. FWIW humans are really good at spotting dynamic changes, so that trick of loading both pages in two tabs then swapping between them will show even tiny changes fairly readily (this "blink comparison" is how astronomers used to find planets, and old school ones still do).

Comment: I've left them a query on their "ask a question" page.

Comment: Looks like marketing naming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just the color. The products are identical. Light & Motion lists their different color variations as separate "products", probably due to some limitation of their store site engine.

Note that there is an Urban 800 Fast Charge version, which in addition to coming in different colors, actually is a different product physically.

Comment: Then why don't they call them "This Light (white case)", "This Light (Blue case)" and so on? Calling them Old Spice, Bogan Module and Affectation Overload just makes people think there's more to it than colours and waste time trying to work out what that is.

Comment: @Móż I don't know, you'd have to ask them. I agree it seems confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone here is correct! The only difference is the color options. The different names refer to the difference colors, otherwise they preform exactly the same.

Comment: How do you know that? Your answers suggests that you know rather than simply speculating like others, but you don't give a source or reference. You're not adding anything to Nathan's answer, and a too-short comment like this is very likely to be deleted.

Comment: @Móż To clarify - this is the authoritative answer from Light and Motion.  They're new to SE obviously.

Comment: Criggie, thanks for submitting the question to their ask page. @user27084, if you are Light and Motion, I'd recommend updating username, avatar, and profile details to give more authority to your answers :)

Comment: Also, maybe tweak the grammar a little to be closer to conventional usage. @Criggie but what makes you think that? I'm really confused.